# I used angular/cli version is 7.1.4. What is the suitable version of angular/fire

Tags: angularfire

I used angular/cli version is 7.1.4. What is the suitable version of angular/fire

I got this error

```
node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts(8072,49): error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.
node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts(8076,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'NextFn'.
node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts(8077,21): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FirebaseStorageError'.
node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts(8078,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'CompleteFn'.
node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts(8094,31): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FirebaseStorageError'.
node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts(8210,24): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FirebaseStorageError'.
node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts(8226,32): error TS2694: Namespace 'firebase.storage' has no exported member 'UploadTaskSnapshot'.
node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts(8236,40): error TS2694: Namespace 'firebase.storage' has no exported member 'UploadTaskSnapshot'.
node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts(8238,29): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FirebaseStorageError'.
node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts(8266,28): error TS2694: Namespace 'firebase.storage' has no exported member 'UploadTask'.
node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts(8735,33): error TS2315: Type 'ReadableStream' is not generic.
```